# Bitcore installation fails in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, bitcoin, bitcore

I have node v9.11.1 and npm v5.8.0.
I am trying too install bitcore by using below command,

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm=true bitcore
```

but it gives me an error as,

```
make: Entering directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bitcore/node_modules/zmq/build'

CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zmq/binding.o
../binding.cc:28:17: fatal error: zmq.h: No such file or directory
#include <zmq.h>
             ^
       compilation terminated.
  zmq.target.mk:95: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/zmq/binding.o' failed
  make: *** [Release/obj.target/zmq/binding.o] Error 1
 make: Leaving directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bitcore/node_modules/zmq/build'
```

I also tried to install zmq globally but gives an error too.
Is there any way to install bitcore ? Please help me to come out of it....

Answer (score -1):

are you already follow this steps ?
.
1.Install ZeroMQ and Tools fir ubuntu /debian

```
$apt-get install libzmq3-dev build-essential
```

.
try to install it..